# XML injection fortify issue

Tags: c#, xml, fortify

I am getting some xml data from database and concatenating them in a string builder and assigning the same in XDocument object.

But fortify is throwing xml injection error for this and saying to validate the same.

How can make it as trusted and fix this fortify issue.

Comment: How did that data get into the database?  Can you really trust it? Perhaps if only you or are trusted source entered it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042016/fortify-access-control-database-related-issue/35605339#35605339 for how to suppress, hide or remove issues.

Comment: @WaltHouser yes those are xml are used as config, And inserted as constant in db